# Error al correr aplicación Ionic en dispositivo móvil

Tags: android, ionic, programación-móvil, capacitor

Hola a todos actualmente estoy creando una App sencilla en Ionic (tan solo son los tabs por defecto que crea el CLI de ionic), pero no puedo ejecutarla en mi dispositivo móvil.

Estoy ejecutando el comando `ionic capacitor run android` como lo dice su documentación, al terminar sale como si todo hubiera salido bien pero nunca se ve la App.

También intente con el comando `ionic capacitor run android -l` y tampoco funcionó, de nuevo en la consola sale todo bien pero no muestra nada.

Esto me muestra la consola al ejecutar `ionic capacitor run android -l`, pero solo puedo verla en mi localhost por el puerto 8101.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Antes que nada ya tengo mi celular en modo desarrollador y habilite la depuración USB, incluso me pide que lo seleccione.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi ionic info

```
 Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.16.1 
(C:\Users\felipe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.6.10
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.0.5
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 12.0.5
@angular/cli                  : 12.0.5
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 4.0.0 

Capacitor:

Capacitor CLI      : 3.0.2
@capacitor/android : 3.2.0
@capacitor/core    : 3.1.2
@capacitor/ios     : not installed

Utility:

cordova-res (update available: 0.15.3) : 0.11.0
native-run                             : 1.4.0

System:

NodeJS : v12.16.2 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm    : 6.14.4
OS     : Windows 10
```

Mientras probaba luego me sale este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
A quien me pueda ayudar se lo agradecería mucho, llevo rato que no puedo probar mis aplicaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser que no le has añadido el Google-servicio.json usarás firebase, por lo tanto el archivo de configuración debes meterlo dentro de la carpeta Android en src creo que es